# How to consume C++ interface in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop

In order to hide the implementation of the function, I usually write the following C++ code and expose my function as 'interfaces'

```
// the interface to expose
class ICalcService
{
public:
    virtual double Multiple(double a, double b) const = 0;
};

// the implementation of the interface
class CalcService final : public ICalcService
{
    virtual double Multiple(double a, double b) const override
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};

// expose the 'CreateCalcService' to mydll.dll as C function 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CreateCalcService(void** obj)
{
    *obj = new CalcService();
}
```

And the typical usage in C++ is

```
// typical way to consume the interface in C++
void test_cpp_code()
{
    ICalcService* calc;
    CreateCalcService(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&calc));
    cout << calc->Multiple(15, 23) << endl;
}
```

**Now I would like to consume it in C# code.** After a period of research, I wrote the following code

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    interface ICalcService
    {
        double Multiple(double a, double b);
    }

    [DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static void CreateCalcService(out object obj);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o;
        CreateCalcService(out o);
        var calc = o as ICalcService;
        calc.Multiple(14, 29);
    }
}
```

**But it won't work as I expected**. Instead, exception was throw at line `CreateCalcService(out o)`.

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidVariant' has detected a problem in 'xx\xx\myloader.vshost.exe'.
Additional information: An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidOleVariantTypeException' occurred in myloader.exe
Additional information: Specified OLE variant is invalid.*

**Could someone kindly let me know what is the issue and how to make it work? e.g. wrong C# dllimport signature.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot call directly into C++ interfaces like that.  There are a couple of alternatives.

1) Wrap the C++ code in C.

```
// expose the 'CreateCalcService' to mydll.dll as C function
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CreateCalcService(void** obj)
{
    *obj = new CalcService();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Multiple(void* obj, double a, double b)
{
    ICalcService calc = (ICalcService)obj;
    calc->Multiple(a, b);
}
```

with C# code like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static void CreateCalcService(out IntPtr obj);

[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static double Multiple(IntPtr obj, double a, double b);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr calc;
    CreateCalcService(out handle);
    Multiple(calc, 14, 29);
}
```

2) Write a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: It's quick disappointed to know that there is no built-in way to approach. The first alternative is really not an elegant way while the second one is not platform crossed :( Anyway, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. C++ interface (which is nothing but a `class`) is different from C# `interface`. You cannot typecast an instance of C++ object to a C# interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
private extern static void CreateCalcService(out object obj);
```

the param is wrong,it can not be object.Try the byte[].  such as

```
byte[] mac = new byte[16];
private extern static void CreateCalcService(mac);
```

Comment: Then how to typecast the byte[] mac to ICalcService?